# How to convert “Ã©” to “é” in PHP?

Tags: php, encoding

I'm trying to convert a string from this: “Ã©” to this: “é”. It's a latin1 character but I can't do it right. So far I've tried two functions but none of them give me the right output.

```
$translation = 'CopÃ © rnico was Italian';
$translation = mb_convert_encoding($translation, 'utf-8', 'iso-8859-1'); //opt 1
$translation = iconv('utf-8', 'latin1', $translation); //opt 2
```

I'm getting this data from an Api so I don't know what's going on in the database.
This is the string in Spanish: Copérnico es italiano. 
This is the data from the API: CopÃ © rnico is Italian
This is the result with $translation = bin2hex($translation);
436f70c38320c2a920726e69636f206973204974616c69616e

What's the right way to go? Greetings.

Comment: Have you tried `utf8_encode()` ?

Comment: Maybe it's already UTF-8 with bad symbols?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UTF-8 all the way through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

Comment: If you see [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake), that means you're not interpreting some bytes using the correct charset. The problem is either that you're merely mis-treating the correct bytes, or that you have messed up data which expresses literally the letters "Ã ©". It's impossible to know which it is with the given information. Start with an `echo bin2hex($translation)` to see what *bytes* the string contains, based on that figure out what charset it is, and then figure out what charset you *want*.

Comment: @NaveedRamzan Yes and it adds more characters:  
$translation = utf8_encode($translation);
CopÃ Â© rnico was Italian

Comment: @deceze I'm getting this data from an Api so I don't know what's going on in the database.

This is the string in spanish: Copérnico es italiano
This is the data from the API: CopÃ © rnico is Italian
This is the result with $translation = bin2hex($translation); 436f70c38320c2a920726e69636f206973204974616c69616e

I can't figure it out what's the charset so any guideline from here would be great. Thanks.

Comment: Put that information into your question.

Comment: I punched re-open but I don't think it's going to go all the way to getting reopened. You need to track down what wrote it wrong and why before you try to kludge-fix it here. Only on knowing the exact incorrect transform can a reversal be given.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same problem before and this option

```
$translation = iconv('utf-8', 'latin1', $translation); //opt 2
```

work verry well.
Your problem is *`CopÃ © rnico was Italian`* is not the same than *`CopÃ©rnico was Italian`*.

So when you try to convert the function **iconv** see 2 wrong UTF-8 symbols because de spaces, is not the same "**Ã  ©** "(2 invalid UTF-8 symbols and 2 spaces) than "**Ã©**"(1 Valid UTF-8 symbol)